# I want to upgrade my power supply but I have a "slim" one

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I need to replace my PSU, Do I have to stick to slim power supplies because I also have a smaller motherboard or is it just based on the amount of power that the computer draws?
.

The slim power supply I use

.
[image]

.
What I would like to upgrade to

.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The wattage of the power supply is completely independent from its size and shape. The physical size of the power supply is only relevant in fitting inside the case and not fouling on the motherboard or its components.

Typically, if your computer came with a slim power supply, odds are you will need a slim one to fit.  This is not always the case, but most often is.

Slim power supplies are often put in small form factor PCs, which are not often designed with higher performance in mind.  So your computer manufacturer might not have a higher wattage PSU, but you should still check with them first.